# fetch image from URL to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

The goal is to have have AWS lambda copy a specific jpg from a URL each day to an S3 bucket. This seems like a super simple lambda function but its just not working. I have this setup as a local NPM project then upload the zipped files in the AWS lambda console. The code below runs without error but does not copy the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
"use strict";

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const Jimp = require("jimp");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const imageType = "image/jpeg";
const bucket = 'mybucket';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let objectKey = 'myimage.jpg';

    Jimp.read('sampleURL.com/image.jpg')
    .then(image => {
        s3.putObject({
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: objectKey,
            Body: image,
            ContentType: imageType
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Handle an exception.
    });


};
```

aws cloudwatch logs

```
2019-10-24T12:48:23.105Z    bac7d80e-5544-4ea5-ae12-478281338389    INFO    { Error: Could not find MIME for Buffer <null>
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (/var/task/node_modules/@jimp/core/dist/utils/image-bitmap.js:120:15)
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (/var/task/node_modules/@jimp/core/dist/index.js:506:32)
    at /var/task/node_modules/@jimp/core/dist/index.js:448:15
    at /var/task/node_modules/@jimp/core/dist/index.js:176:14
    at /var/task/node_modules/@jimp/core/dist/request.js:66:9
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/phin/lib/phin.compiled.js:1:2100)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) methodName: 'constructor' }
END RequestId: bac7d80e-5544-4ea5-ae12-478281338389
REPORT RequestId: bac7d80e-5544-4ea5-ae12-478281338389  Duration: 612.63 ms Billed Duration: 700 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 97 MB  Init Duration: 557.69 ms
```

Comment: Do you have anything at place of  `// Handle an exception.`? If there is nothing, then it might be that the real exception is hidden from you. `console.log(err)` should help with that.

Comment: It would be great if you could also share the output from Lambda in CloudWatch for debugging purposes.

Comment: good call on the logging. This recorded a MIME and buffer issue that I added above. Searching this leads to several git threads that were never solved. At this point I'd greatly appreciate suggestions on a different script to download and save the img to S3.

Answer (score 2):

If this helps anyone else the image needed to be written to a buffer. The following line fixed it:

```
const buffer = await image.getBufferAsync(imageType);
```

Then buffer is used for the S3 Body parameter. so the full script is:

```
    "use strict";

    const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    const Jimp = require("jimp");
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const imageType = "image/jpeg";
    const bucket = 'bucketxzy';

    exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
        let objectKey = 'sampleimage.jpeg';
        const image = await Jimp.read('https://www.sampleurl.com/sampleimage.jpg/');
        const buffer = await image.getBufferAsync(imageType);

        return s3.putObject({
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: objectKey,
            Body: buffer,
            ContentType: imageType
        }).promise();


    };
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you are downloading the entire image into memory rather than streaming the image. There's no reason that a streaming solution, correctly written, would not work.

Comment: Saved my life damn!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to stream a file from an HTTP URL into S3. It uses promises/async/await rather than callbacks and it dispenses with the Jimp package, about which I know little, in favor of the more traditional `fetch` API:

Note: if you do not explicitly supply a content-type when uploading to S3 then it will be set to `application/octet-stream` which will be problematic when clients are downloading the object. So this code determines the content type of the file first, and sets it when streaming to S3.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const stream = require('stream');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const uploadStream = ({ Bucket, Key, ContentType }) => {
  const pass = new stream.PassThrough();
  return {
    writeStream: pass,
    promise: s3.upload({ Bucket, Key, ContentType, Body: pass }).promise(),
  };
}

const uploadFetch = async ({ url, Bucket, Key, ContentType }) => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const { writeStream, promise } = uploadStream({Bucket, Key, ContentType});
  response.body.pipe(writeStream);
  return promise;
}

exports.handler = async (_event, _context) => {
  const source_jpeg = {
    Key: 'audi.jpeg',
    Bucket: 'mybucket',
    url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Audi_A3_2015.jpeg',
  };

  // HEAD the source image to get content type
  const rc_head = await fetch(source_jpeg.url, {method: 'HEAD'});
  const content_type = rc_head.headers.get('content-type');
  console.log('head:', rc_head.status, rc_head.statusText, content_type);

  try {
    // GET the source image and stream it to S3
    const parms = {...source_jpeg, ContentType: content_type};
    const rc_upload = await uploadFetch(parms);
    console.log('get/upload jpeg:', rc_upload);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Also, be sure that your Lambda function is configured with a reasonable timeout (the default timeout is 3 seconds).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this returns the same error message that I posted above "errorMessage Could not find MIME for Buffer <null>",

Comment: @RyanK this code works fine for a regular JPEG, such as the one I used in the code. It does not yield 'Could not find MIME for Buffer'. That error message comes from the Jimp package, which I am not using in my answer, so I am assuming that you must have modified my answer, introduced Jimp, and re-introduced the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

One common issue in those cases is a permission error. To allow AWS Lambda to PutObject in S3, you need to set such permissions in the Lambda Execution Role.

Here is an example of a policy that will allow Lambda to do anything in S3:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::ExampleBucketName",
                "arn:aws:s3:::ExampleBucketName/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For security purposes, it is important to restrict the action to only the ones you actually need, such as PutObject, and you can get more information on [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this does have the necessary permissions. I'm using the same role from another function that writes to S3